# Laravel sqlite migration not working properly

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I am using Sqlite for test database. When i run a factory it is showing

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "auto_increment": syntax error`

from SQLite documentation they have `autoincrement` not `auto_increment`.

how do I can define a primary key or auto increment for sqlite?

I am using RefreshDatabase trait.

Migration:

```php
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name', 100);
```

factory:

```php
$factory->define(Teacher::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});
```

phpunit.xml

```xml
   <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
```

config/database.php

```php
 'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
....
```

testcase

```php
public function user_can_visit_teachers_page()
    {
        $teacher = factory('App\Models\Teacher')->create();

        $response = $this->get(route('teachers.index', $teacher->id));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Full error message is:

```sh
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "auto_increment": syntax error (SQL: create table `teachers` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(100) not null))
```

- Laravel 5.8
- PHPUnit 7.5.17
- PHP 7.2
- I have `pdo_sqlite` enabled on my `php.ini` file.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: so it migrates the 'users' and 'password_resets' tables but fails on 'teachers'?

Comment: yea, thats weird.
 `dd(Schema::connection($this->getConnection())->getConnection()->getSchemaGrammar());`
gives me this:  [https://pastebin.com/u9CyMdyQ](https://pastebin.com/u9CyMdyQ)

Comment: that is something you have added, you will have to not have that being used during tests ... find what ever service provider is dealing with that

Comment: I just showing it to you for debugging purpose

Comment: `App\Services\ExtendedMysqlGrammar` is something you have added to your application .. you will have to not use that while testing

Comment: Got it. I need that for some of my migrations. How can I disable it for testing?

Comment: i dont know your code, but basically what ever is being done to use your own custom grammar isn't the correct way, it should only be used for mysql connections and it seems to be used for all connections

Comment: just fixed it. could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change it by following this sample. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

```
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name', 100);
```

Comment: it won't work. The problem is with eloquent grammar generate `auto_increment` which is incorrect for sqlite.